# Loading on canvas in facebook doesn't work...?

Tags: image, loading, facebook-canvas

My server gives a pretty bad response time for facebook apps.
I want the show a loading image while it's still a blank page.
I tried via ajax but that didn't work, since I include a file that does the auth part, and redirects to the same page when auth is successful.
Tried some other things to (like jquery) but that didn't work either.

Anyone knows how to do it? I know how to do this on a regular website, but it doesn't work in Facebook... The loading image needs to appear when the page is polling the facebook servers to get user ID, name, about_me, etc.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page is an iframe canvas page, you could return a basic page with a loading image and then use jquery, XMLHttpRequest, or other ajax techniques to populate the rest of the page.  You should also make sure you are caching the user data so that you don't have to wait for Facebook to return it everytime.

It also sounds like you could use a better server.